# UITableViewCell animate button constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UITableView that detects a swipe from left to right. I want to show a delete button when the user does the swipe by changing the constant of the width constraint on it. But no matter what I try to do the button won't animate or change width at all. The only way I can get the button to display the constraint change is by reloading the row.

This is what I have right now. Every answer I see contains this method of animating constraints.

```
 func TableViewSwipeRight(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
 {
    let point = gesture.location(in: favoriteStationsTableview)
    let indexPath = favoriteStationsTableview.indexPathForRow(at: point)

    if let indexPath = indexPath {
        if let favoriteCell = favoriteStationsTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FavoriteCell.GetReuseId(), for: indexPath) as? FavoriteCell {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            favoriteCell.deleteBtnConstraint.constant = 50
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the cell at the given `indexPath` and not dequeue it (as it won't be part of the tableview at this point.)

```
if let indexPath = indexPath {
   if let favoriteCell = favoriteStationsTableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FavoriteCell
   {

   }
```